# MediaPlayer pause() выкидывает ошибку NullPointerException

Tags: java, android, mediaplayer

Пытаюсь написать простой аудио плеер, который играет файлы из папки `res/raw` на фоне.

Есть два класса.

В `MyService`, в методе `OnCreate`, запускается `Mediaplayer`:

```
public class MyService extends Service {
MediaPlayer mp;
final String TAG = "AUDIOPLAYER";

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

    mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.fawaid_1);
    playSound();
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    // TODO: Return the communication channel to the service.
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not yet implemented");
}


public class MusicBinder extends Binder {
    MyService getService() {
        return MyService.this;
    }
}

public void pausePlayer(){
        mp.pause();
}
public void playSound(){
    mp.start();
}
```

В `MainActivity` на кнопку повешен метод `pausePlayer()` из класса `MyService`.

Код `MainActivity`:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
TextView curTimeText;
Button playB;
Button seekB;
Button pauseB;
SeekBar seekPlayer;
Context c;
final String TAG = "AUDIOPLAYER";
Handler handler;
SharedPreferences sp;
String spStr = "bookSettings";
private MyService myService;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    final Button playB = (Button) findViewById(R.id.playB);
    Button pauseB = (Button) findViewById(R.id.pauseB);
    Button seekB = (Button) findViewById(R.id.seekB);
    SeekBar seekPlayer = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekPlayer);

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyService.class);
    startService(intent);

    MyService myService = new MyService();
    pauseB.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            MyService service = new MyService();
            service.pausePlayer();
        }
    });
}

private ServiceConnection musicConnection = new ServiceConnection(){

    @Override
    public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder service) {
        MyService.MusicBinder binder = (MyService.MusicBinder)service;
        //get service
        myService = binder.getService();

    }

    @Override
    public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name) {

    }
};
```

При запуске приложения аудио начинает проигрываться, но при нажатии *pauseB* программа выкидывает ошибку `NullPointerException`:

```
07-20 19:09:50.395    4153-4153/? W/System.err﹕ java.lang.NullPointerException
07-20 19:09:50.395    4153-4153/? W/System.err﹕ at ru.grawor.islamicaudiobooks.MyService.pausePlayer(MyService.java:40)
07-20 19:09:50.395    4153-4153/? W/System.err﹕ at ru.grawor.islamicaudiobooks.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:62)
07-20 19:09:50.395    4153-4153/? W/System.err﹕ at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438)
07-20 19:09:50.395    4153-4153/? W/System.err﹕ at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18422)
07-20 19:09:50.395    4153-4153/? W/System.err﹕ at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
07-20 19:09:50.395    4153-4153/? W/System.err﹕ at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
07-20 19:09:50.395    4153-4153/? W/System.err﹕ at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
07-20 19:09:50.395    4153-4153/? W/System.err﹕ at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
07-20 19:09:50.395    4153-4153/? W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-20 19:09:50.395    4153-4153/? W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
07-20 19:09:50.395    4153-4153/? W/System.err﹕ at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
07-20 19:09:50.395    4153-4153/? W/System.err﹕ at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
07-20 19:09:50.395    4153-4153/? W/System.err﹕ at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Как сделать так, чтобы при нажатии *pauseB* проигрывание приостанавливалось?

Answer (score 1):

```
MyService service = new MyService();
service.pausePlayer();
```

Тут вы создаете новый объект вашего `Service` при таком способе использования метод onCreate у сервиса вызван не будет. Для того чтобы это работало вы обязаны использовать  `myService` который инициализируется в методе `onServiceConnected`. Этот метод будет вызван после того как сервис создасться, то есть в том числе будет уже вызван метод onCreate. А до тех пор поставте проверку поля `myService` на NPE в `onClickListener`

Answer (score 1):

Вы используете сервис не правильно. Вам следует прочитать документацию по использованию сервисов, этого будет достаточно чтобы решить Вашу задачу http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/guide/components/services.html

Не вызывайте `MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.fawaid_1);` в `onCreate` сервиса, это заблокирует основной поток выполнения Вашей программы. Прочитав документацию по сервисам Вы будете знать, что сервис выполняется в основном потоке программы.

Comment: Благодарю за ответ. Для большей уверенности, можете подсказать где вызывать этот метод (create())?

Comment: @JoeSilent в onStartCommand стартуете отдельный поток и в нём вызываете MediaPlayer.create.

Comment: Решений полно в [гугле](https://www.google.ru/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=service%20media%20player%20android) вот [один из вариантов](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/create-a-music-player-on-android-song-playback--mobile-22778)

Comment: огромное спаибо за помощь! постараюсь разобраться